# function use .env variables are undefined after export, so function can't work after export in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, .env

I attempted to configure a MySQL connection pool using **`mysql2`** and environment variables, intending to export it to another file.

In **`database.js`**, I export the pool to another file after loading the environment variables from the **`.env`** file:

```
import { createPool } from 'mysql2';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });

export const pool = createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST, 
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
}).promise();
```

However, in **`api/user/user.service.js`**, when attempting to import the pool for accessing MySQL data, I encountered an issue:

```
import { pool } from '../../config/database.js';

async function getAll() {
    const result = await pool.query(`
    SELECT * FROM user`);
    console.log(result);
}

getAll();
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sql: undefined,
sqlState: '28000',
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

Strangely, when I directly input my personal data in **`database.js`** like this, the **`user.service.js`** file works:

```
export const pool = createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1', 
    user: 'root',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'database_name'
}).promise();
```

I'm puzzled about the issue with my **`.env`** file.

This is my path:

```
project_folder
├── config
│   └── database.js
├── api
│   └── user
│       └── user.service.js
└── .env
```

I want to know what's wrong with my .env file

Comment: `../.env` is interpreted relative to the directory of the node process. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761165/16462950).

Comment: Note that the recommendation for dot-env is to run it as _early_ as possible, not "in the place you need it" (because that place will change throughout the lifetime of your codebase). Usually this means putting it at the top of your `index.js`, living in the same dir as your `.env` file, so you don't even need to specify a `path` argument. Once run, any code that runs afterward (no matter where in your filetree it is) gets access to the same, updated, `process.env` content.

Comment: I have placed my `.env` file in the same directory as my `index.js` and imported it at the top of `index.js`. I have also tried to print my environment variable in another file in different dir, and it can retrieve the value. However, I still can't utilize the exported function that uses the environment variable